# Search results "floating" over rest of the page?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am made a instant search feature for my website as you can see here: harrisonbh.com/chatterr/instant_search/ but the search results just push down the content.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search Box</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php  
    //include 'connect.php';
    include '../core/database/connect.php';
?>

<span id="box">
    <input type="text" id="search_box"><button id="search_button">Search</button>
</span>

<div id="search_result">
</div>

Rest of content

</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var left = $('#box').position().left;
    var top = $('#box').position().top;
    var width = $('#box').width();

    $('#search_result').css('left', left).css('top', top+32).css('width', width);

    $('#search_box').keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();

        if(value != ''){

            $('#search_result').show();
            $.post('search.php', {value: value}, function(data){
                $('#search_result').html(data);
            });
        } else {
            $('#search_result').hide();
        }

    });

});
```

search.php

```
<?php

    //include 'connect.php';
    include '../core/database/connect.php';
    $value = $_POST['value'];

    $search_query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE '$value%'");
    while ($run = mysql_fetch_array($search_query)){
        $username =  $run['username'];

        echo '<a href=#>'.$username.'</a><br/>';

    }

?>

body{
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    background:#fff;
}

input{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(210, 210, 210, 210);
}

button{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    background:#4aaee7;
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(210, 210, 210, 210);*/ 
}

button:hover{
    background:#fff;
    color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(210, 210, 210, 210);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#search_result{

}

/*#search_result {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(210, 210, 210, 210);
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}*/

a {
    background:#4aaee7;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -14px;
    display: block;
}

a:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color: #4aaee7;
}

ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

I'm not sure if i should be using `position: absolute;` or what to fix this. What do you think that I should do? Thanks.

Comment: Put a case when returns something...i made a search and nothing returns

Comment: The search returns usernames from my datavase

Comment: Give us a default username, to see a "floating" result on your: harrisonbh.com/chatterr/instant_search/  example ;)

Comment: Search for `harrison` or `max`

Comment: try <div id="search_result" style="clear:both;"></div>

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just enclose you input text field and search button in `<div style="float:left;">`

I mean, like this:

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <span id="box">
        <input type="text" id="search_box"><button id="search_button">Search</button>
    </span>

    <div id="search_result">
    </div>
</div>
```